# Add two 32-bit integers in Assembler for use in VB6

Tags: optimization, assembly, vb6, addition

I would like to come up with the byte code in assembler (assembly?) for Windows machines to add two 32-bit longs and throw away the carry bit. I realize the "Windows machines" part is a little vague, but I'm assuming that the bytes for `ADD` are pretty much the same in all modern Intel instruction sets.

I'm just trying to abuse VB a little and make some things faster. So as an example of running direct assembly in VB, the hex string `"8A4C240833C0F6C1E075068B442404D3E0C20800"` is the assembly code for `SHL` that can be ["injected" into a VB6 program](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftLeft.htm#ShiftLeft04) for a fast `SHL` operation expecting two Long parameters (we're ignoring here that 32-bit longs in VB6 are signed, just pretend they are unsigned).

Along those same lines, what is the hex string of bytes representing assembler instructions that will do the same thing to return the sum of two 32-bit unsigned integers?

The hex code above for `SHL` is, according to the author:

```
mov eax, [esp+4]
mov cl, [esp+8]
shl eax, cl
ret 8
```

I spit those bytes into a file and tried unassembling them in a windows command prompt using the old debug utility, but I figured out it's not working with the newer instruction set because it didn't like `EAX` when I tried assembling something but it was happy with `AX`.

I know from comments in the source code that `SHL EAX, CL` is `D3E0`, but I don't have any reference to know what the bytes are for instruction `ADD EAX, CL` or I'd try it. *(Though I know now that the operands have to be the same size.)*

I tried [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/download.php) and am not getting anything I can figure out how to use. I used it to assemble the original `SHL` code and got a very different result, not the same bytes. Help?

Comment: *add two 32-bit longs and throw away the carry bit* - that would be `lea eax, [ecx + edx]` / `ret` if we're talking about __fastcall, otherwise `mov` load / memory source `add` / `ret`.   (the carry flag isn't part of the return value).  You're totally over-complicating this, and IDK why calling an asm function would be faster than using `+` in VB source code.  Also, `add eax, cl` is not encodeable because the operands are different sizes.

Comment: Also, it still seems unlikely to me that VB overhead around passing args to a machine-code function would be lower than calling its own implementation of `+`.  Does that not just do wrapping math for a fixed-width integer type? Binary addition is the same operation for 2's complement as for unsigned, so if VB6 doesn't have unsigned types, IDK how you're going to get the result of this asm back into VB in a useful way.  Does VB `+` widen integers to extended precision instead of wrapping, making it slower?  If so they yes, it's certainly plausible for asm to be faster by truncating the result.

Comment: Also, if you have a contiguous *array* of items to add up, doing the whole loop in asm should be *much* faster.  You can even use SSE2 `paddd xmm0, [edx]` to do 4 adds at once (SIMD), with 2/clock load and add throughput.  If not, then making a function call for every add sucks, but still might suck less than whatever you can get VB to do on its own, IDK.  Been ages since I ever did anything with VB.  (And most of that was writing a native function in C I could call from VB in excel to do some data fitting like 60x faster than native VB code, for a summer student job 20 years ago.)

Comment: Are you distinguishing between VB6 and VB.Net? VB6 cannot do unsigned addition of 4-byte long integers. However, it can make calls to Windows API methods through COM, passing bytes directly through without conversion, so that a signed long in VB is received by the Windows API correctly as an unsigned long. This all worked flawlessly and I was able to add the two 32-bit values together and get the value back. Doing this in VB6 natively would require complicated conditionals or bit manipulation to handle the sign bit separately from the rest of the bits. There was no contiguous array.

Comment: @PeterCordes my question's title and first paragraph all say that I want to add two 32-bit values, so I'm not sure what is driving annoyance? As for performance, contrary to possible intuition, using VB6 to do Windows API calls is actually *very* fast.

Comment: No, I don't know enough about VB to know anything about versions, sorry.  What happens in VB6 if you do `x += 1` with `x = 0x7ffffffff`?  Do you get `-2147483648` (C INT_MIN)?  If so, you can do regular `+` and pass the result to a function that wants an unsigned long and it will Just Work, because it has the bit-pattern `0x80000000`, same as unsigned `2147483648`.  You only need to work around the `+` operator if it detects signed overflow and does something other than 32-bit wrapping.

Comment: Oh well, didn't hurt to ask.  I guessed it might be that the language you're using detects signed overflow but wanted to find out.  A significant fraction of assembly-language questions on Stack Overflow *are* a result of people not understanding binary.  Unfortunately dealing with that flood of newbie questions has an impact on my default assumptions.  I was surprised a language wouldn't have a way to do unsigned integer math, and guessed wrong that it might be easier than this.  Sorry again for wasting your time.

Comment: It wasn't you asking, it was the way you asked. For what it's worth, if you have ANY office product, launch the VB editor and try stuff in the Immediate pane. Or search online. VB6 is an ancient language. Did you notice the year on the question? Sorry for the acerbity. I guess I let myself get irritated, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disassembled the bytes you provided and got the following code:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
f:
00000000    movb    0x08(%esp),%cl
00000004    xorl    %eax,%eax
00000006    testb   $0xe0,%cl
00000009    jne     0x00000011
0000000b    movl    0x04(%esp),%eax
0000000f    shll    %cl,%eax
00000011    retl    $0x0008
```

Which is definitely more complicated than the source code the author provided. It checks that the second operand isn't too large, for example, which isn't in the code you showed at all (see Edit 2, below, for a more complete analysis). Here's a simple `stdcall` function that adds two arguments together and returns the result:

```
mov  4(%esp), %eax
add  8(%esp), %eax
ret  $8
```

Assembling that gives me this output:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000 8b 44 24 04 03 44 24 08 c2 08 00
```

I hope those bytes do what you want them to!

Edit:  Perhaps more usefully, I just did the same in C:

```
__attribute__((__stdcall__))
int f(int a, int b) 
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Compiled with `-Oz` and `-fomit-frame-pointer` it generates exactly the same code (well, functionally equivalent, anyway):

```
$ gcc -arch i386 -fomit-frame-pointer -Oz -c -o example.o example.c
$ otool -tv example.o
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_f:
00000000    movl    0x08(%esp),%eax
00000004    addl    0x04(%esp),%eax
00000008    retl    $0x0008
```

The machine code output:

```
$ otool -t example.o
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000 8b 44 24 08 03 44 24 04 c2 08 00
```

Sure beats hand-writing assembly code!

Edit 2:

@ErikE asked in the comments below what would happen if a shift of 32 bits or greater was attempted.  The disassembled code at the top of this answer (for the bytes provided in the original question) can be represented by the following higher-level code:

```
unsigned int shift_left(unsigned int a, unsigned char b)
{
    if (b > 32)
        return 0;
    else
        return a << b;
}
```

From this logic it's pretty easy to see that if you pass a value greater than 32 as the second parameter to the shift function, you'll just get `0` back.

Comment: That looks super. Thanks helping me out in my ignorance. Do you have a recommended assembler/disassembler? Free, hopefully? Or does Microsoft have one? Also, what happens if you try to SHL more than 32, say some very large number?

Comment: I just used gcc/otool on my Mac.  They were free.  If you need to use windows, cygwin has free tools you can use.  Microsoft definitely has tools too, but I have no idea if they are free or where to get them.

Comment: @Emtucifor, I'll edit my answer to address your question about shifting more than 32 bits.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured was happening, an optimization for 32 bits and up. But wouldn't the shl instruction return 0 anyway for >= 32? I searched for the testb instruction but couldn't find out how the value 224 does the job of testing for 32, unless it's some kind of `255 - n` mask or involving reverse bit order or something.

Comment: @Emtucifor, yes - the instruction set manual says "The count operand can be an immediate value or the CL register. The count is masked to 5 bits..." which does make it seem the check in the original code is unnecessary.  The value 224 in hex is 0xe0 - bits 5, 6, and 7 are set.  Any number with one of those bits set is greater than 32 - 2^5=32.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't paying attention. I see it's a perfectly valid bit mask of the top 3 bits, and it must set the NE flag to false if the second operand has any bits set in the mask of the first operand. Or something like that. Thanks a lot for your help! You've been super and I like to learn arcane stuff like this...

Comment: Note: shift-left of 32 bits or greater will not return 0, because using 32 or greater in a shift-left is an undefined operation. That is why one must check the size of the shift before performing it, or one will get garbage out.

Comment: Yup - that's what that code block at the end of my answer shows, I think?

Comment: Right... my new comment was just for any future visitors, to clarify something about the SHL instruction itself—the higher-level code you provided does indeed imply that checking for `b >= 32` is required, but doesn't state that explicitly or say clearly what will happen if one tries. (The issue about SHL 32 being undefined actually came up recently for a developer friend of mine, and I just happened to come across this old question today and I thought I'd call out this small fact for any future readers.)

Comment: Gotcha. Approved. ;-)